# How does an Enumeration variable works?

Tags: java, object, enums

Consider `enum Animals { DOG, FISH, GOAT };` in Java.

Now the variable of type `Animals` can point to member objects of this type:

`Animals a1 = Animals.DOG;` that's fine.

But how do the following chain references makes sense ?

`Animals a2 = a1.DOG.FISH.GOAT;` (yea, looks crazy, seen this in a tricky Java question)

what does `a1` *really* point to ? and how are we referencing other `enum` members from it ?

**Example:**

```
public class EnumTest {
    enum Animals { DOG, FISH, GOAT };

    public void test(){
        Animals a1 = Animals.DOG;
        Animals a2 = a1.DOG.FISH.GOAT; //--Strange but valid--
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this valid Java syntax? Never saw something like that. And even if it is valid, I guess it's the same as `Animals.GOAT` so it's just obfuscating the real intention.

Comment: You're referencing a static member through an instance of it. Eclipse will give you a warning: `The static field Animals.DOG should be accessed in a static way`.

Comment: @Koraktor Compiles fine.

Comment: @AlvinWong Updated with example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Members of an `enum` in Java are just like static fields of a class, so `a1.DOG` is simply the same as `Animals.DOG`.

```
public class EnumTest {
    enum Animals { DOG, FISH, GOAT };

    public void test(){
        Animals a1 = Animals.DOG;
        Animals a2 = a1.DOG; // the same as Animals.DOG, but makes code messy
        Animals a3 = a1.DOG.FISH; // WTF chaining???
    }
}
```

This doesn't only happen on `enum`s, but also `class`es:

```
public class A {
    public static A a_1;
    public static A a_2;

    public void boo() {
        A a = A.a_1;
        A b = a.a_1; // That makes a equal to b!
        A c = a.a_1.a_2; // I HATE "CHAINING" LIKE THIS
    }
}
```

Just as @lichengwu has pointed out in his/her answer, `enum`s will finally compile into a class with static fields, so this is not a problem of `enum`s, but rather like the problem of `class`es.

In some other languages (for example C#) you are not allowed to reference a static member of a type through an instance of the type, but Java is an exception.

IMHO referencing a static member of a type through an instance of the type should be a bad habit. This causes confusion like you have pointed out.

---

If you like using the Eclipse IDE, it will simply give you a warning:

> The static field Animals.DOG should be accessed in a static way

Eclipse also provides a few suggestions for you. One of them is to change to using the type to reference the `enum` member, and another one is to remove the "static modifier of the field" (but doesn't actually work on `enum`s).

**Addition:**

Internal structure of what the Enumeration compiles to:

```
final class Animals extends java.lang.Enum<Animals> {
  public static final Animals DOG;
  public static final Animals FISH;
  public static final Animals GOAT;
  public static Animals[] values();
  public static Animals valueOf(java.lang.String);
  static {};
}
```

Comment: So, `A b = a.a_1.a_2` will compile ?

Answer (score 5):

Decompilation the `Animals.class`

`javap Animals.class`:

```
final class Animals extends java.lang.Enum<Animals> {
  public static final Animals DOG;
  public static final Animals FISH;
  public static final Animals GOAT;
  public static Animals[] values();
  public static Animals valueOf(java.lang.String);
  static {};
}
```

All types are Animals's instance, so you can reference other type.

Answer (score 2):

What you have demonstrated is a consequence of how Java handles enum types. Enum type constants are static references and not numerical primitives like in C. Since you can access static members of a type (in this case `Animals`) through an object/instance reference (`Animals.DOG`), you can always get to any other enum constant from any enum constant. The trick here is the static member is a reference to an instance of the type of which it is a member.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` creates its elements as static instances of this `enum`. In some cases these instances are subclasses of this `enum`.

Of course, you can access class methods and class instances (i.e. static) using objects.